# Display value of an array that has numbers as it's key (within an ng-repeat)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the follow array of arrays in my controller (script.js file):

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('oneController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.countries = [{
      "name": "Aruba",
      "code": "ABW",
      "1960": 54208,
    }];
```

In my index.html file, I am running an ng-repeat to display a table with country name, code, and population in 1960.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <h1>Challenge Three</h1>
  <div ng-controller="oneController">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="country in countries">
        <td>{{ country.name }}</td>
        <td> {{ country.code }}</td>
        <td> {{ country.1960 }}</td>
      </tr>
```

country.name and country.code show up in the table, but country.1960 does not. Is there a certain syntax I have to use for "1960" to make it work properly?

Answer (score 2):

You need to access it using brackets:

```
{{ country["1960"] }}</td>
```

Comment: You're a legend! Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You should also be able to use the following:

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="(key,val) in countries[0]">
<td ng-bind="key"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This won't generate the same output ...will have 3 rows instead of 3 columns and will output keys not values